# C++ Arguments to SGX Enclave Edge Functions

Tags: c++, stl, sgx, enclave

I'm trying to write a simple SGX enclave that takes in a vector of booleans, but apparently edger8r creates c code; so the edl code

```
enclave{

  from "sgx_tstdc.edl" import *;
  include "BetaDist.h"
  include <vector>

  trusted {
         BetaDist Estimate(std::vector<bool> X, double max_z, double max_delta); 
  };

  untrusted {
  };
};
```

produces a compile error (Amusingly, the Intel compiler reports it under the title "catastrophic error") saying header `vector` can't be found.

It seems to me that the problem can be solved just by compiling the output edge code with a c++ flag. Would that work? Even if so, is there a cleaner way to do this (i.e. having edge functions with C++ standard-typed parameters)?

PS: I don't have enough rep to add a new tag, would anyone tag this with 'edger8r'? It'll be helpful I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#include` is incorrect EDL syntax. No need for hash - `include`

Arguments in ecalls and ocalls have to be C type - so, `vector` and `bool` are not supported.

For `vector` you need to convert it into C type (maybe create a struct or void pointer), then pass a pointer with its length.

For `bool`, I guess, better to pass an `int` to represent a Boolean value.

You also have to specify special attribute for pointers:

- `[in]` - if you want to copy it into enclave (you also need to specify its length) (aka pass by value)
- `[out]` - if you want to copy back from enclave
- `[user_check]` - the easiest option - you just pass a pointer and enclave will read from and write to untrusted memory. (aka pass by pointer)

Do not forget to cast arguments back into C++ types!

Comment: you may add a piece of code for your suggested solution. it will be more clear