# Passing vector to enclave in Intel SGX

Tags: c++, c, sgx

I have a `vector<vector <string>> a`; How could I pass it to the enclave? How I declare edl function.
A sample function declaration for the app, edl and enclave is much appreciated.

I am aware of this: [C++ Arguments to SGX Enclave Edge Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41901884/c-arguments-to-sgx-enclave-edge-functions).

A sample to pass even a `vector<string>` is ok for me.

update1:
I came up with this:

App.cpp

```
const char *convert(const std::string & s)
{
   return s.c_str();
}

vector<string> members_data;
member_data.push_back("apple");
member_data.push_back("orange"); //just for sample

    std::vector<const char*>  vc;
    std::transform(members_data.begin(), members_data.end(), std::back_inserter(vc), convert);
```

edl:

```
trusted {
       public void ecall_receive_vector([in, size=len] const char **arr, size_t len);
};
```

enclave

```
void ecall_receive_vector(const char *arr[], size_t len)
{
    vector<string> v(arr, arr+len);

    printf("%s\n", v[2].c_str());

}
```

But enclave does not receive any data, the program compiles perfectly with no error. Could anyone help? The printf is the sample ocall.

Comment: And what kind of problems you're having in terms of implementing that which is hinted towards in the answer to that other question?

Comment: I am not able to comprehend the hint.

Comment: Could you provide the caller code?

Comment: The accepted answer is correct.

Comment: yes but I have a similar problem that I am trying to figure out (this would help me)

Comment: Post your question, share the question link here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the EDL use `count` instead of `size`.

```
trusted {
    public void ecall_receive_vector([in, count=len] const char **arr, size_t len);
};
```

You are passing a double pointer, it is, a pointer to pointer to char (`char **`).

While marshaling/unmarshaling pointers, the EDL Processor processes (copies and validates input and output) only the first level of indirection, it's up to the developer to handle the additional levels of indirection. Hence, for an array of pointers it will only copy the first array of pointers, not the pointed values, copying them is the developer's responsibility.

If not specified `count` and `size` default to `1` and `sizeof(<pointed-type>)` respectively. In your case `size = sizeof(<pointer>)` which in most platforms is `4`.

In your case, you provided only `size`. As you don't provide the caller code I assume you're passing the length of the string, and as `count` was not specified it defaults to `1`. Then the total number of bytes, based on `Total number of bytes = count * size` will be `1 * len` which is wrong.

Using only `count` will let `size` default to `sizeof(<pointed-type>)`, then `Total number of bytes = count * size` will be `count * sizeof(<pointed-type>)`, which is right because you're passing an array of pointers.

To close, once inside the Enclave you need to copy the pointers' data because those pointers reside out of the enclave, that may be done automatically by assigning them to a `std::string`.

---

From Intel SGX SDK Documentation:

> [**Pointer Handling**](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/708975) (*the last paragraph*)
>
> You may use the direction attribute to trade protection for performance. Otherwise, you must use the `user_check` attribute described below and validate the data obtained from untrusted memory via pointers before using it, since the memory a pointer points to could change unexpectedly because it is stored in untrusted memory. However, the direction attribute ***does not help with structures that contain pointers. In this scenario, developers have to validate and copy the buffer contents, recursively if needed, themselves***.

And,

> [**Buffer Size Calculation**](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/708979)
>
> The generalized formula for calculating the buffer size using these attributes:
>
> `Total number of bytes = count * size`
>
> - The above formula holds when both `count` and `size/sizefunc` are specified.
> - `size` can be specified by either `size` or `sizefunc` attribute.
> - If `count` is not specified for the pointer parameter, then it is assumed to be equal to `1`, i.e., `count=1`. Then total number of bytes equals to `size/sizefunc`.
> - If `size` is not specified, then the buffer size is calculated using the above formula where `size` is *`sizeof (element pointed by the pointer)`*.

Comment: Could you explain it a little why it matters if I write len instead of size

Comment: It's not `len` it's `count`. `len` is the name of the variable you're using.

Comment: _"You want to pass a double pointer"_ What do you propose to pass in this new argument?

Comment: I meant 'you are passing', fixed now!.