# Best way to convert 2D vector to C type (for SGX enclave)

Tags: c++, c, vector, sgx, enclave

I'm trying to write an SGX enclave that takes in a 2D vector of int (representing a grayscale image), but edger8r accepts only C types.

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48871693/passing-vector-to-enclave-in-intel-sgx) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41901884/c-arguments-to-sgx-enclave-edge-functions), but could someone provide an example on how to transform a type like:

```
vector< vector <int> > ImagePixels;
```

into a C type so that I can pass it to an SGX enclave?

Comment: When you say "a C type" what specific "C type" do you mean?

Comment: Any C type would actually work (e.g., as answered by Goran Flegar), I simply need to convert this vector object in such a way that edger8r can compile it and pass it to the enclave; then I would convert it back into a vector object once in the enclave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::vector` has a `data()` method that will give you a plain pointer to its data. However, you'll need to do something with that second layer of vectors, so you'll need to create a temporary array that will store a list of plain pointers from the inner vector.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


extern "C" int my_c_function(int **double_pointer, int rows, int cols) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
            printf("%d ", double_pointer[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}


int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> ImagePixels{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};

    // transform a vector of vectors into a vector of pointers
    std::vector<int*> ptrs(ImagePixels.size());
    std::transform(begin(ImagePixels), end(ImagePixels), begin(ptrs),
        [](std::vector<int> &inner_vec) {
            return inner_vec.data();
        });

    my_c_function(ptrs.data(), ImagePixels.size(), ImagePixels[0].size());
}
```

Live example: https://onlinegdb.com/BJvb3yG3f

However, if you have control of the entire code, I would suggest using a flat structure, where you just store the whole picture into a falt `std::vector<int>` row-by-row. You could even do a simple wrapper around std::vector to make it easier to manipulate such a structure:

```
class image {
public:
    image(int rows = 0; int cols = 0)
        : rows_{rows}, cols_{cols}, data_(rows * cols) {}

    int &operator ()(int row, int col) {
        return data_[row * cols_ + col];
    }

    int *data() { return data_.data(); };

    // needs a few more utilities and constant versions of the methods
private:
    std::vector<int> data_;
    int rows_;
    int cols_;
};
```

Then you can do:

```
image im(3, 2);
// set pixels
im(0, 0) = 1;
im(0, 1) = 2;
int *d = im.data(); // a plain pointer to an array of data
```